# Typescript assigning variable in ngAfterViewInit not working

Tags: angular, components, angular2-components

I am trying to create a component in angular 4 and am running into a very strange issue which i cant seem to solve.

I have a simple `boolean` that i an trying to set based on a `@Input`

```ts
@Input('type') inputType: string = 'text';
showTextInput: boolean = false;
...
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('input', this.inputType);
    this.showTextInput = this.inputType === 'text' ? true : false;
    console.log('after condition', this.showTextInput);
}
```

This html for the component is

```ts
<ts-input-item formControlName="name" 
               [control]="programForm.controls.name" 
               [label]="'Name'" 
               (onUpdateClicked)="updateItem($event,'Name','name')"> 
</ts-input-item>
```

so in its current form it *should* default to type `text`, which it kinda does, and this is were i am getting very confused. Below is the `console.log` prints.

[image]

So now `this.showTextInput` is equal to `true`. However if i then use this in the component like so

```ts
  <ion-input #input 
             [type]="inputType" 
             [disabled]="isSelect"
             (keyup)="itemValueChanged(input.value)" 
             (keyup.enter)="itemUpdate()"
             *ngIf="showTextInput">
  </ion-input>
```

Then the component breaks completely. Mainly because it does not show as the parent component does not handle the form name being passed, but to put it simply, if i even add something like

```ts
<div *ngIf="showTextInput"> foobar </div>
```

The `foobar` text will not show and there is no error. Am i handling the pass in the correct lifecycle hook?

Comment: Do you get an error in the browser console?

Comment: No, not for the simply example, for the `*ngIf` on the `ion-input` it is a reactive form issue stating that the `name` form element is not avalible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invoking change detection explicitly might help:

```ts
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('input', this.inputType);
    this.showTextInput = this.inputType === 'text' ? true : false;
    console.log('after condition', this.showTextInput);
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. I actually couldnt work out how to get `ChangeDetectorRef` but when i was searching i saw i could implement `OnChanges` I am not sure how different that is but i be diving deeper. cheers.

Comment: Updating the model in `ngOnChanges` usually also requires `cdRef.detectChanges()`. What do you mean with "hot to get `ChangeDetectorRef`"? Just import it from `@angular/core`.

Comment: Yeah i got it working with `ChangeDetectorRef` not sure what i did wrong before

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Glad to hear you could make it work.

Comment: Thanks so much, I used this in my solution after bumping my head against the wall for half a day :)

Comment: What about subscriptions inside ngAfterViewInit or ngOnInit?

Comment: @RavinderPayal what about them? I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer sir I am really not able to comprehend this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467529/angular-7-changedetectorref-detectchanges-causes-infinite-loop-when-called-fr

If we subscribe something like route parameters inside ngAftrerViewInit or ngOnInit and assign them to fields which are bound to template I get this famous ExpressionChangedAfterCheck, and If I use `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` inside subscription callback, I fall in trap of infinite loop.